# Seasonal Adjustment of Daily Data

Tags: r, seasonality

I have daily data with only weekday values. So my week is 5 days in my data set. I want to use `TBATS` function in R. I am suspecting weekly, bi-weekly, monthly and annual seasonality in my data after periodogram check. In this case how should I define the `seasonal.periods` in `tbats` function? Would this be ok:

```
x <- msts(x, seasonal.periods=c(5, 10, 21.66, 260))
```

I am little confused because my year is not equal to `365.25` days. So can I just assume my year is `= 365.25 * 5/7`?

I am sorry if this question was asked before but I couldn't find an answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your msts object looks right, but if you are trying to do seasonal adjustment rather than forecasting, I recommend using `mstl()` rather than `tbats()`.

```
library(forecast)
library(ggplot2)
x <- msts(x, seasonal.periods=c(5, 5*2, 365.25*5/7/12, 365.25*5/7)
mstl(x) %>% autoplot()
mstl(x) %>% seasadj() %>% autoplot()
```

Answer (score 2):

You might want to review https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A3382+DAILY+DATA for a comprehensive discussion of how to handle daily data which can be affected by holidays , day-of-the-month , level shifts , time trends , pulses , week-of-the-month , long-weekends , et al . IMHO TBATS is broadly insufficient to deal with opportunities like these to correctly analyze daily data.

Delete all non-seasonal factors thus the fitted values reflect the "seasonally adjusted series" as the fitted values just reflect the seasonal component and no other factor/feature.

In reponse to OP's comment

What you refer to as "seasonality" are simply omitted exogenous variables/factors . These can be identified and incorporated as such. Your seasonality is not endogenous i.e. rear-window arima stuff BUT exogenous. If you post you data I would be glad to be more analytical/specific. You may be an "arima person i.e. a rear-window predicter" but there is a more structured/generalized approach called Transfer Functions which is sometimes referred to as XARMAX model or ARMAX models that explicitely incorporate fixed effects like day-of-the-week , week-of-the-month , day-of-the-month, month-of-the-year, level shifts , time trends et al AND also arima structure..

Comment: Hi, thanks for the link. My data is daily contract announcements. So my seasonality mostly comes from budgetary cycles and start-end of fiscal calendar. I thought TBATS would do the job for me. I tried with the specification just to begin. I subtract the sum of 4 seasonal components from observed values and end up with sum of levels+irregular term. Unfortunately, I have negative values. I am not sure if using dummy variables is good idea in such case.

Comment: .....................................................

Comment: I put figure of my data if it helps.

Comment: NOTSOMUCH .. post the actual data .....